# What is the difference between $|u|u$ and simply $u^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across an equation for drag force which is $F = X_u u+X_{u_|u|}u|u|$ where $X_u$ is the drag force derivative with respect to $u$ while $X_{u_|u|}$ is the drag force derivative with respect to $u|u|$. My question is if $u|u|$ and $u^2$ are same then why we write it as $u|u|$ or if these two are different then can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: Try $u = -1$, for example.

Comment: Note:  unlike $|u|$, $u|u|$ is differentiable everywhere

Comment: Although I learned something, the comments and answers helped. And I don't know why my question is down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $u\ge0$, then $|u|=u$, so $u|u|=u^2$; but when $u<0$, then $|u|=-u$, so $u|u|=-u^2$